# Display modal bottom sheet above system navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet, edge-to-edge

I would like to display a modal bottom sheet above the system navigation bar when using edge-to-edge display.
I mean the system navigation bar and the bottom navigation bar.

Here is how I set up the edge-to-edge display:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
 systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
 systemNavigationBarContrastEnforced: false,
 systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
 statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
 statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
 statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
));
runApp(ProviderScope(child: App()));
```

The problem is that when using edge-to-edge the system navigation bar sometimes overlap content on the bottom sheet.
I can't post any screenshots right because of `Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server`, but I would provide them as soon as image upload is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap the content of the Bottom modal with a SafeArea widget. If it doesn't work, try to add a bottomPadding like this:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom),
```